# Datepicker opened by "show()" function need a click

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I Have 2 datepicker (checkin and checkout date). When the user select the first date, my script open automatically the second datepicker, through

```
$("#checkout").datepicker('show');
```

ok.
My problem is that in this second calendar, when the user click on right arrow to change the month, the calendar is closed (1 second) and re-opened. So, the user must click twice for change month. 
How I can solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Post code on a jsfiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ajm3/1/

So: select a date of checkin (ie, 26 february). You see that the calendar "checkout" is open automatically. Now, try to change mounth (ie from february to march). You must click twice.